# PHP: looping through an array of objects and displaying the sum of all records in the first row

Tags: php, loops

Let's say i have the following array:

```
$array = [
    ['time_spent' => 10, 'rate' => 150],
    ['time_spent' => 20, 'rate' => 100]
];
```

I want the table to look like the following:
It has 2 rows and 4 columns (Time Spent, Rate, Total, Grand Total):
The first row will be:

```
10 | 150 | 10 x 150 = 1500 | 3500
```

and the second row:

```
20 | 100 | 10 x 200 = 2000
```

(3500 is the sum of the total of both records)

Comment: where are the object? when is the code you using? which problem you encounter? which table you want? DB?

Comment: Json? This isn't the syntax of a PHP array.

Comment: Hi Tony, could you show us your solution, even if it doesn't do what you want, and tell us what you have problems with?

Comment: Do you really have an array with two json strings?

Comment: @Tony, Let us know what you have tried (code) yourself. So that we can help you telling in which part you need correction. 
It's not a good method to ask to write entire program for you. Also this is just for-loops program. You need to add PHP code to the loops.

Comment: Showing the grand total on the first row is pretty unusual. It's not where most people would expect to look for it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you you wanted to output an HTML table, something like this would work.

```
$array= [
    ["time_spent"=> 10, "rate"=> 150], 
    ["time_spent"=> 20, "rate"=> 100] 
];
$html = [];
$sum = 0;
foreach ($array as $i => $row) {        
    $product = $row['rate'] * $row['time_spent'];
    $line = "<tr><td>{$row['time_spent']}</td><td>{$row['rate]'}</td>";
    $line .= "<td>{$row['time_spent']} x {$row['rate']} = {$product}</td>";
    if ($i !== 0) {
        $line .= '</tr>';
    }
    $html[] = $line;
    $sum += $product;
}

$rowCount = count($html);
$html[0] .= "<td rowspan='{$rowCount}'>{$sum}</td></tr>";

echo '<table>' . implode('', $html) . '</table>';
```

EDIT: Changed code to reflect the change in input.

Note that there would be better ways to simply calculate total sum.  This method generates the desired display along with the sum with a single loop through the data.

Comment: When imploding with an empty string as glue, that parameter can be omitted.

Comment: @mickmackusa - true, but I prefer to include it since it makes the intention much clearer

Answer (score 0):

Using html template strings with `s/printf()` does a great job of keeping clean, readable code with separation between processing and markup.

I am purposely making this script verbose. The advantage in this script is readability and maintainability.

It is an unusual requirement to have the grand total in the right column of the table instead of the final row of the table.  If you desired the total to be in the final row, then the code would be easier to write and read (for humans).

In my demo, click on the eye icon in the upper right of the output box to see the html rendered version of the result.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/vEKrZ))

```
$array = [
    ['time_spent' => 10, 'rate' => 150],
    ['time_spent' => 20, 'rate' => 100]
];

$tableMarkup = <<<'HTML'
<table>
%s
%s
</table>
HTML;

$headerRowMarkup = <<<'HTML'
    <tr>
        <th>Time Spent</th>
        <th>Rate</th>
        <th>Total</th>
        <th>Grand Total</th>
    </tr>
HTML;

$firstRowMarkup = <<<'HTML'
    <tr>
        <td>%1$d</td>
        <td>%2$d</td>
        <td>%1$d x %2$d = %3$d</td>
        <td rowspan="%4$d">%5$d</td>
    </tr>
HTML;

$subsequentRowMarkup = <<<'HTML'
    <tr>
        <td>%1$d</td>
        <td>%2$d</td>
        <td>%1$d x %2$d = %3$d</td>
    </tr>
HTML;

$rowsMarkup = [];

$count = count($array);
if ($count) {
    $grandTotal = array_reduce(
        $array,
        function ($carry, $row) {
            $carry += $row['rate'] * $row['time_spent'];
            return $carry;
        },
        0
    );

    $row = array_shift($array);
    $rowsMarkup[] = sprintf(
        $firstRowMarkup,                   // template string
        $row['time_spent'],                // %1$d
        $row['rate'],                      // %2$d 
        $row['time_spent'] * $row['rate'], // %3$d
        $count,                            // %4$d
        $grandTotal                        // %5$d
    );
}

foreach ($array as $row) {
    $rowsMarkup[] = sprintf(
        $subsequentRowMarkup,
        $row['time_spent'],
        $row['rate'],
        $row['time_spent'] * $row['rate']
    );
}

if ($rowsMarkup) {
    printf(
        $tableMarkup,
        $headerRowMarkup,
        implode("\n", $rowsMarkup)
    );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to calculate the grand total before you start printing the table. Then you can show it on the first row of the table.

```
$grand_total = 0;
foreach ($array as $item) {
    $grand_total += $item['rate'] * $item['time_spent'];
}

echo "<table>";
foreach ($array as $i => $item) {
    $total = $row['time_spent'] * $row['rate'];
    echo "<tr><td>{$row['time_spent']}</td><td>{$row['rate']}</td>";
    if ($i == 0) { // first row, show grand total
        echo "<td>$total</td><td>$grand_total</td>";
    } else {
        echo "<td colspan='2'>$total</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```